# Parsing date throws NumberFormatException with Empty String ""

Tags: java, parsing

I wanted to parse some date, and for whatever the reason, parsing the date throws an error. I am using IntelliJ to debug it and from what I see, either IntelliJ is showing me a different stack, or something is happening beyond my understanding. I am using `jdk 1.8.0_261` in my local, and I am debugging a remote machine which has `jdk 1.8.0_291`

**EDIT**: One thing to mention, this bug does not happen all the time. I am using the same and different values for dates and from time to time, it throws an exception. So, although I give "15/04/2021" for an input string, it is not 100% guaranteed that I will face an exception.

This is the thing that I wanted to parse:

`return sf.parse((String)properties.get("validfrom"));`

sf is `SimpleDateFormat`

`public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException`

method is called with the source being "15/04/2021"

[DateFormat.java/parse method, line 364](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOJKo.png)

Then, `DecimalFormat.java/parse` method, `digitList.getLong()` is called. The digitlist seems to have
"0.2021x10^4"

[DecimalFormat.java/parse, digitList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWRz.png)

Deeper in the stack, `Long.parseLong` is called with the same "0.2021x10^4"

[Long.getLong()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPR86.png)

[Long.getLong() 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NBtf.png)
(To capture another picture of the line of codes being executed, I have re-executed from the beginning, that is why the object Id's are different.).

Suddenly, the string passed to `parseLong()` becomes ""

[static long parseLong(String s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCxZL.png)

In the end, it throws an exception.

The weirder thing is, when I try to execute  `return sf.parse((String)properties.get("validfrom"));` inside debugger mode, with evaluation (pressing alt + clicking on the line) it does not throw an error, and it returns me what I am expecting, the date.

What am I missing in here? Somehow the inner workings of java library between 1.8.0_261 and 291 is changed?

SimpleDateFormat was created via `this.sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);`

Stack trace

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at java.text.DigitList.getLong(DigitList.java:195)
        at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2082)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:2162)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1514)
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:364)
        at com.foo.bar(baz.java:123)
```

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] and a complete stack trace. All the digging into the JRE source code is good, but it's all a bit confusing when we can't see your original source code (e.g. how `sf` is set up). Rather than try to debug through the JRE, I'd try to fix the problem within *your* code, as that's likely to be feasible... but we can't really help you do that without a [mcve].

Comment: Did you set a pattern in the SimpleDateFormat object?
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is being set up via ```this.sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);``` . Unfortunately, I cannot give you the minimal reproducible example because it is just impossible. The bug that I have mentioned above does not happen all the time. I am passing the similar values again and again. Although the values are the same or in the same format, "sometimes" it throws an exception
. But I am adding the stacktrace for additional information

Comment: Are you shure, that you do not access the SimpleDateFormat from different Threads? SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe!

Comment: Indeed, given the facts that a) you're using a field for your `SimpleDateFormat`; b) it doesn't happen all the time; c) you see the right results in the debugger, this sounds *very* much like it could be a threading issue. (Note that if you used java.time instead, this wouldn't be a problem. Try to move away from java.util.Date etc as soon as you can...)

Comment: Oh, that could be the reason. As I said, I am remote debugging a machine. It has the production application and I know that we have bunch of threads. Although I am not specifically creating threads to parse the date, maybe, somewhere in the application another thread is trying to use my ```baz``` class and tries to parse another (maybe the same value) date.

Comment: Under all circumstances I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is not thread-safe.

[`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in Java 8 is immutable and thread-safe alternative to `SimpleDateFormat`. You should use the new java.time classes if possible

Comment: Of course the OP can use `DateTimeFormatter` and the other classes from java.time. They are reporting that they are using Java 8.